# Could not deduce MonadReader in ReaderT wrapping

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, reader-monad

Following and adapting [this blog post](https://making.pusher.com/unit-testing-io-in-haskell/), I've been trying to produce a solution which should allow testing of a function which reads env vars (using [System.Environment.lookupEnv](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.0/base-4.14.1.0/System-Environment.html#v:lookupEnv)).

That way, I should be able to inject an artificial environment for tests which can be read in place of performing the actual IO action.

However, the type check fails when attempting to read the env.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving #-}

...
import           RIO.Map (Map)
import qualified RIO.Map as Map
...
import qualified System.Environment as E (lookupEnv)
...

newtype MockEnv m a = MockEnv
  { mockEnv :: ReaderT (Map String String) m a
  } deriving (Applicative, Functor, Monad, MonadTrans)

runMockEnv :: MockEnv m a -> Map String String -> m a
runMockEnv (MockEnv e) = runReaderT e

class Monad m => MonadEnv m where
  lookupEnv :: String -> m (Maybe String)

instance MonadEnv IO where
  lookupEnv = E.lookupEnv

instance Monad m => MonadEnv (MockEnv m) where
  lookupEnv k = Map.lookup k <$> ask
                              -- ^^^ error occurs here
```

At the site of "ask" above, the following error is produced:

```hs
/home/[REDACTED].hs:45:34: error:
    • Could not deduce (MonadReader (Map String String) (MockEnv m))
        arising from a use of ‘ask’
      from the context: Monad m
        bound by the instance declaration
        at [REDACTED].hs:44:10-40
    • In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘ask’
      In the expression: Map.lookup k <$> ask
      In an equation for ‘lookupEnv’: lookupEnv k = Map.lookup k <$> ask
   |
45 |   lookupEnv k = Map.lookup k <$> ask
   |                                  ^^^


--  While building package [REDACTED]
```

Please could you help me understand why this fails to type check and what I need to do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types don't look like they match up.  We have:

```hs
lookupEnv :: String -> MockEnv m (Maybe String)
k :: String
ask :: MonadReader r m => m r
Map.lookup :: Map.lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a
Map.lookup k :: Map String a -> Maybe a
```

So, this all means we need the bit where you currently have `ask` to be of type `MockEnv m (Map String a)`.  The simplest solution is to wrap up `ask` with your `MockEnv` newtype wrapper.  For instance, the following works:

```hs
  lookupEnv k = Map.lookup k <$> MockEnv ask
```

The more robust solution (and the one that GHC hints at with its suggestion that you need a `MonadReader` instance) is to let `MockEnv m` be an instance of `MonadReader`:

```hs
instance Monad m => MonadReader (Map String String) (MockEnv m) where
  ask = MockEnv ask
  local f (MockEnv r) = MockEnv (local f r)
```

With this instance, your instance definition for `MonadEnv (MockEnv m)` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, and the first suggestion solves the issue. I had at one point tried writing an instance of MonadReader as you suggested but found that doesn't typecheck - `Illegal instance declaration for ‘MonadReader (Map String String) (MockEnv m)’ (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*, and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.` Do you know why that is? It recommends using flexible instances but that still won't compile (same error)

Comment: Actually, it works with MultiParamTypeClasses as well. I'll do some reading to make sure I understand what I'm doing using these extensions. Thanks for your help :)